# Is an application-wide "settings table" a good idea?

Tags: database, web-applications, persistence

Wordpress, for example, has a table with `name => value` rows for storing application-wide settings (the name of the blog, comments settings, etc.). Please note that I'm referring to settings that may be modified often during normal use of the application.

I understand why Wordpress does it like that (portability: it's easy to copy the entire database to another blog and retain settings), but is there a better way to do it for smaller applications?

I know that many frameworks, like Zend Framework for example, have a configuration file with application-wide configuration settings. Why not just dynamically modify that file at runtime to save my settings? To me, this has several advantages over database settings storage:

- Less database use
- Settings are easily human-editable over FTP without needing a MySQL shell or phpMyAdmin instance
- Settings files can easily be backed up and restored

On the other hand, the biggest complication I can think of is that of concurrency. The file will need to be locked while changes are being made.

What is the preferred way?

Comment: If the settings will be modified often put it in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## DB table advantages

- Settings are global to all web servers sharing the same database. No need for file replication/network file system
- The application most likely already uses database, no extra setup
- No dependencies on file system
- Easier to cache (maybe there is already some generic DB caching layer?)
- Handles concurrency
- The application may already have a framework or a way to handle CRUD of any database table (creating GUI is easy)
- Transparent backup with the rest of your application
- Can be strongly typed if you have several `value` columns of different types used exclusively

## ...and disadvantages

- you need a tool or SQL knowledge to maintain it
- *might* have a worse performance

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! I'm going to hold off accepting answers for a little bit, to see if there are any other opinions, but I like yours a lot.

Comment: Oops, completely forgot about this question. Thanks for the answer!